# Windows Server 2019 doesn't display my active networks

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2019

I have a new server with Windows Server 2019 Datacenter (with Desktop environment) installed. Soon after I installed Windows Update, enable NIC teaming, enabled RDP, enabled Windows Defender, and joined it to my local domain, I logged on and noticed that I could not see my active networks anymore but I could still connect via RDP to the server.

When I go to 'View your active connections' section in Network and Sharing Center window, all I could see is "*the dependency service or group failed to start*".

I have searched the internet and found this answer on [MS forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-1068-the-dependency-service-or-group-failed/649b2787-51b5-47db-a9c2-4c814a6bee8d) about turning on or restarting the required Services and referencing other suggestions but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: given that the networking is working properly, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What do you mean by "See active networks"? Where? What is an active network?

Comment: This is what I mean by "See active networks", there is a part in "Network and Sharing Center" that show 'public network', 'private network' or 'domain network'. In my case it doesn't display any of those but 'the dependency service or group failed to start'.

I was able to drill further and found that the teamed nic is not connecting to the internet and the firewall settings are off and not responsive. I can manually toggle on/off firewall in Windows Defender Firewall, but it will not come 'on' or go 'off'.

I'm a little uncountable to add this server to existing hyper-v cluster.